# How to keep remote powershell command alive after session end?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, remote-access

I use the following command to run `setup_server.exe` on remote Windows box:

```
powershell -command "$encpass=convertto-securestring -asplaintext RPASSWORD -force;$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList RUSER,$encpass; invoke-command -computername RCOMPUTERNAME -scriptblock {setup_server.exe} -credential $cred;"
```

`setup_server.exe`'s task is to create some configuration files and start `my_server.exe` (some daemon process), then it finishes. And I want `my_server.exe` to keep running after `setup_server.exe` is finished.

So when I do it via CMD on local box (i.e. just run `setup_server.exe` from CMD) it works, but when I do it via powershell on remote host it doesn't work. Namely the `my_server.exe` gets started, but right after `setup_server.exe` is closed the server also gets closed(killed).

So the question is following:
Which powershell flags/cmdlets should I use to make the described scenario to work as in local mode?

NOTE: I want synchronously get output of `setup_server.exe`, so running remote command with `-AsJob` flag, probably wouldn't work for me, though I even don't know if it will keep the server alive after `setup_server.exe`'s end.

Comment: either create a service or a scheduled task to run your exe ?

Comment: Does it work if you start `setup_server.exe` via `Start-Process` (non-blocking for the ps session) instead of directly?

Answer (score 1):

The way to keep the remote PowerShell session running after the command has finished is to use a PSSession e.g.:

```
$s = new-PSSession computername
Invoke-Command -session $s { ..script.. }
... do other stuff, remote powershell.exe continues to run
Remove-PSSession $s # when you're done with the remote session
```

Generally though exes should run independently from the app that launched them.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer @Keith Hill, but it doesn't work. I've tried this:
`powershell -command \"\$encpass=convertto-securestring -asplaintext mypassword -force;\$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList myuser,\$encpass;\$session = new-PSSession -computername HOSTNAME -credential \$cred; invoke-command -session \$session -scriptblock {setup_server.exe};\"` but again the server was killed right after setup_server is done.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Invoke-Command. If you want a persistent Session, use Enter-PSSession.

```
$s = New-PSSession -Computername "Computername";
Enter-PSSession -Session $s;

setup_server.exe

# Once you are finnished
Exit-PSSession
```

With 'Enter-PSSession' you are not just Invoking some Command on the Server, you are directly logged-in like you probably know from SSH.

Comment: `# Once you are finnished` this would not happen. I want to start remote server and that is all. Then I want to exit the session keeping the server running on remote host.

Comment: If you don't close the shell, I think the session should remain open. At least for some time... With 'New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeOut ??? -OperationTimeOut ??? -CancelTimeOut ??? -OpenTimeOut ???' you can setup the Timeouts: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849703.aspx

Comment: I do it in script, so shell gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your powershell session to keep running because you are running an exe, try using the -InDisconnectedSession switch.  From what I understand, it will run the executable on the remote machine in a session that isn't actually connected to your computer.  In essence, your computer will not destroy the session, when it disconnects, allowing the exe to continue to run.

invoke-command -computername RCOMPUTERNAME -scriptblock {start-process setup_server.exe} -InDisconnectedSession

If you need to do this on multiple computers.  Setup an array of all the computer names.

Note: I don't believe this works with sessions that are already created.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep a powershell code running on the session exit it should be a process. And the windows way to keep the process is running a .exe or a windows service.